# mongodb cannot be connected in nodejs on openshift

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift

I am learning nodejs/mongodb  . I am using openshift to host my nodejs+mongodb test code . I am able to run the same on my local setup . I did basic changes and tried to ran it on my openshift setup . However i am unable to do so .

My basic code is

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
Server = require('mongodb').Server,
CollectionDriver = require('./collectionDriver').CollectionDriver;

  var connection_string = 'mongodb://'  + 'admin:LLEasswrd@' +
  '127.12.12.130' + ':27017' +
  '/' +
  'bugmanish';


var mongoClient = new MongoClient(connection_string); //B
mongoClient.open(function(err, mongoClient) { //C
  if (!mongoClient) {
      console.error ("process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD["+process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD+"]");

      console.error("Error! Exiting... Must start MongoDB first connection_string ["+connection_string+"]");
      process.exit(1); //D
  }
```

The get error

```
Error! Exiting... Must start MongoDB first connection_string [mongodb://admin:LLEasswrd@127.12.12.130:27017/bugmanish]
```

Mongodb logs last few line

```
Sun Jan  4 10:38:32.131 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
Sun Jan  4 10:38:32.131 [initandlisten] options: { auth: true, bind_ip: "127.12.12.130", command: [ "run" ], config: "/var/lib/openshift/54a8f64de0b8cd608a000132/mongodb//conf/mongodb.conf", dbpath: "/var/lib/openshift/54a8f64de0b8cd608a000132/mongodb/data/", nohttpinterface: "true", noprealloc: "true", pidfilepath: "/var/lib/openshift/54a8f64de0b8cd608a000132/mongodb/pid/mongodb.pid", quiet: "true", smallfiles: "true" }
Sun Jan  4 10:38:32.135 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/openshift/54a8f64de0b8cd608a000132/mongodb/data/journal
Sun Jan  4 10:38:32.135 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Sun Jan  4 10:38:32.922 [initandlisten] preallocateIsFaster=true 2.12
Sun Jan  4 10:38:33.923 [initandlisten] preallocateIsFaster=true 12.94
Sun Jan  4 10:38:35.823 [initandlisten] preallocateIsFaster check took 3.61 secs
Sun Jan  4 10:38:35.917 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Sun Jan  4 10:38:37.014 [conn1]  authenticate db: admin { authenticate: 1, nonce: "d6319d8c9990fd23", user: "admin", key: "45a07cf6275ca202367c4bdbf66095c0" }
```

Comment: in your local machine did you run the ../mongod service ?If so have you done the same thing in openshift?

Comment: mongdb is already running ..  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017

Comment: Your question says "on OpenShift", but you might have meant "in local development".  The [cloud-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloud-env) or [config-multipaas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config-multipaas) modules might be useful here.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are hard coding your connection info instead of pulling it from the ENV.

Something like this should work:

```
var cc          = require('config-multipaas'),
    mongojs     = require('mongojs');

var config      = cc({ 
  collection_name : process.env.COLLECTION_NAME || process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME || 'parks'
})
var db_config        = config.get('MONGODB_DB_URL'),
    collection_name  = config.get('collection_name');
var db = mongojs(db_config + collection_name, [collection_name] );

function select_all(req, res, next){
  console.log(db);
  db[collection_name].find(function(err, rows){
    if(err) {
      res.send(500, {http_status:500,error_msg: err})
      return console.error('error running query', err);
    }
    res.send(rows);
    return rows;
  });
};
```

I have a few more selector examples available here: https://github.com/ryanj/restify-mongodb-parks/blob/master/bin/db.js

You could also try using the [cloud-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloud-env) or [config-multipaas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config-multipaas) modules to autoconfigure your app.

Comment: i hardcoded because  when I do print on process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME or any other variable i get undefined . If I look up  ~/.env directory i do find these files and hence these should have some automatically . DO i need to do something else to get the access of these variables ?

Comment: @Ryanj I will try with your example  .  Can you also tell me what is the problem with my code given that I have hardcoded the values from the environment variable . It will help me understand my mistakes . ie why  my mongoClient is null with right configuration passed ??

Comment: @MAG could you paste the last 2-3 lines of the log of mongod running in open shift.

Comment: @harryy000 the logs your asked for are appended in the question as i am not allowed to put so much lines here

Comment: thanks,but what was the command you used to run mongod?Ishould have mentioned this as well../mongod the full command

Comment: On openshift one does not need to run mongodb yourself . once u configure it ,  it runs itself and all the configuration is present in terms on environment vairbales which can be easily accesed .

Comment: on displayig error string i get   error running query [Error: Server parameter must be of type Server, ReplSet or Mongos]  . Can you suggest what this means

Comment: `process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME` will be undefined when you run your code locally.  I usually include some fallback values so that my code will run locally as well as on OpenShift ( var connection_string = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL || 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'; )

Comment: The openshift-provided IP address (for connecting to mongodb) will not work in local development environments.  If you want to connect to the remote DB instance from your local dev environment, I'd [try setting up port-forwarding](https://blog.openshift.com/set-up-local-access-to-openshift-hosted-services-with-port-forwarding/)

Comment: By using this var mongoClient = new MongoClient( new Server ( "127.12.12.130" , 27017 ) );  my error goes away and it syas server startd  but I am not able to open any page